# Is precise interrupt important from software's point of view?

Tags: cpu-architecture, interrupt-handling

I recently learnt about precise interrupt and imprecise interrupt in computer architecture class. Is precise interrupt important from software's point of view? If so why is it so?

Comment: dont you find any link on google regarding that???

Comment: I was looking for the importance of precise interrupt from SOFTWARE's point of view, and I couldn't find them. Maybe I didn't check from corner to corner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A precise interrupt leaves the processor in a well-defined state. The consequence is that the running program can be resumed with no risk of error. Resuming will usually be a simple and cheap operation (return from interrupt, or something similar). Most device interrupts fall into this category.

Any other kind of interrupt means that the running program cannot be safely or easily resumed. If it can be resumed at all, the steps to do so are likely to be complex and time-consuming. If it cannot be resumed, then the running program (and perhaps the system) will have to be terminated. A 'panic' interrupt triggered by failing hardware would fit into this category.

The concept is familiar, but I'm not sure these particular terms are in widespread use. Be careful when you use them that your audience understands what you mean.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) Is it correct to say that, if a computer architecture does not guarantee precise interrupt, exception handling(as in Java) cannot be realized?

Comment: No. Interrupts happen 'below the radar' and are invisible to a Java program (unless they cause a 'panic'). I'm pretty certain no physical architecture can guarantee all interrupts will be 'precise'. Java exceptions are created at a far higher level.